# How to use "Layout.alignment" instead of "anchors.right: someItemID.right"

Tags: qml

I have this statement inside my QML item:

```
Rectangle {
    // ...
    anchors.right: someItemID.right
    // ...
}
```

I'm receiving this warning for my `Rectangle` item:

> QML Rectangle: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.

How can I use `Layout.alignment` to resolve the above warning? How can I pass another item ID to `Layout.alignment`? Is it possibe?

Comment: Layouts and anchoring items are two different mechanisms, see [Qt Quick Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html) and [Positioning with Anchors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html) for further reading.

Comment: @JanWin Looks right. Thanks.

Comment: @JanWin If they are different mechanisms, why is the warning telling us to use Layout.alignment instead of anchors?

BTW the warning appears when I'm using RowLayout to manage horizontal layout and anchors to manage the vertical. This should be possible and has been so for many Qt versions.

Comment: The warning appears if you use anchors in a layouted item. You can layout items and then use anchors for items inside those items.

Answer (score 2):

A layout manages the positions and sizes of all of its child items. Using anchors inside child items is not allowed as it could override these rules. You can only influence those properties provided by the layout in the [`Layout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) object attached to its children, which is hinted at in the warning message. [`Layout.alignment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#alignment-attached-prop) controls how the item is aligned within the cell created for it by the layout. You can therefore align an item to the edges of its adjacent cells, but you can't directly anchor to their items by ID.

If you need more precise control, you should position the items outside the layout using position and/or anchor properties.